# Get the students which have attempted exam in current year and at least one previous attempt in last 12 months

Tags: sql, mysql, self-join

I have a task to get the common students who have taken the exam in the current month (November 2023) and must have taken at least one attempt in last 12 months as well. So the look back period is of 12 months.

There's another condition that the student should have got at-least 20 marks in previous attempt(s).

The attempt count can be >= 1. Subject doesn't matter. `Roll_number` would be the joining condition.

This is the query I tried :

```
select 
    roll_number, substr(Exam_Date, 1, 7) yr_mon, 
    count(roll_number) as total_count 
from 
    students_results 
where 
    exam_date between '2022-11-30' and '2023-11-30'
    and marks > 20 
    and exists (select roll_number 
                from students_results
                where marks > 20
                group by roll_number
                having count(SupplierID) >= 1);
```

Sample data:

| Roll_number | Exam Subject | Exam_Date | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | English | 2023-08-01 | 30 |
| 100 | Science | 2023-09-05 | 50 |
| 100 | English | 2023-11-15 | 80 |
| 101 | English | 2021-04-01 | 65 |
| 101 | Science | 2023-06-10 | 45 |
| 101 | English | 2023-11-17 | 85 |
| 102 | English | 2021-04-01 | 70 |
| 102 | Mathematics | 2023-09-01 | 15 |
| 102 | Mathematics | 2023-11-19 | 60 |
| 104 | English | 2023-05-01 | 40 |
| 104 | English | 2023-11-03 | 75 |
| 105 | Mathematics | 2023-04-01 | 10 |
| 105 | English | 2023-11-14 | 80 |

So, we are expecting to get `Roll_number` : 100, 101, 104

I am trying to learn to write the self join query.

Preferred language : HiveQL/ MySQL

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own and explain where you are stuck. BTW I would look at using an EXISTS statement

Comment: doesn't seem any of the record satisfy your description

Comment: Btw, do you have an unique id column in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like homework

We are looking for are records

`FROM` sample_data

`WHERE` the exam date is greater than one month subtracted from the current date (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

`AND` there `EXISTS` (https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_exists.asp) another record in the table for the same roll_number and subject

- `WHERE` the exam_date is earlier

  `AND` the exam_date is greater than 1 year from the current date

  `AND` the mark is greater than 20

Comment: Just want to point out that 1. in first `WHERE`, the exam date is in current month, 2. in `EXISTS`, `exam_date` is within 1 year from current date, you can look at the `DATE_ADD` function 3. in `EXISTS`, another `AND` the record should not be the one selected from the main query. This might be tricky if you don't have unique id column in your table

Comment: @Liu Yeah, I was struggling to phrase that. But the "WHERE the exam_date is earlier" in the exists clause will prevent the outer record from matching itself, provided the student can't retake the exam on the same day. Since it's all just existence not having a surrogate id shouldn't muddy the waters too much.